# How to Update Data in dynamically created table in Android?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have created a dynamic Table which contains a picture,name,date & etc.That data comes from Server in XML Format which I have parsed.My Table is created perfectly.
But My problem is if xml data is updated while I am viewing my Table so simultaneously how can I update the table's data .
Hope you got my problem ..
Please Help ME

Comment: What do you mean 'table'. Is it DB table or table layout?

Comment: Do you wand update data of specific row or just add/remove rows or both?

Comment: better if you switch to a ListView: with a easy style-process you can get the same look&feel of a TableView and you can take advantage of the Adapter for updating data

Comment: @Sunil I tried with ListView but There is a problem i.e I have used buttons in row that has some functionality And that doesn't work well with ListView

Comment: @woodshy I want to update both but for now Data updation will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any clear system for updating data that is not removing all child and adding the new based on the new data received.

In my opinion it's better if you switch to a ListView: with a easy style-process you can get the same look&feel of a TableView and you can take advantage of the Adapter for updating data.